# PSET4: Filter (more comfortable): blur function

Tags: c, cs50

This is an exercise from [CS50 pset4 (more comfortable)](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/more/). This is part of a larger piece of code and it is the blur function. I am having trouble fixing my code.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp_img[height][width];
    // copy original image array
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp_img[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    // iterate throughout the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int sumBlue = 0;
            int sumGreen = 0;
            int sumRed = 0;
            float count_pix = 0;

            // obtain value of original colour values around target pixel- red green blue
            for (int r = -1; r <= 1; r++)
            {
                for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
                {
                    // logic to determine if pixel is existent
                    if ((0 <= i + r && i + r < height) && (0 <= j + c && j + c < width))
                    {
                        // add all RGB values accordingly, with counter
                        sumBlue += temp_img[i + r][j + r].rgbtBlue;
                        sumGreen += temp_img[i + r][j + r].rgbtGreen;
                        sumRed += temp_img[i + r][j + r].rgbtRed;
                        count_pix ++; //count number of iterations to average out later
                    }
                }
            }
            // average out and add replace values into original image for output
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / count_pix);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / count_pix);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / count_pix);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Below is the list of expected output and output from this code

:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
expected "127 140 149\n", not "123 137 145\n

:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
expected "80 95 105\n", not "85 100 110\n

:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
expected "70 85 95\n", not "65 80 90\n

Comment: Typo: `temp_img[i + r][j + r]` ==> `temp_img[i + r][j + c]` on three lines.

Comment: Do you have the input set for the failed tests? Are they small? Then you can [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program quite easily, for example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code statement by statement to see what happens. If none of the failed input sets are small, then the best way to figure it out is probably still by debugging your program, it will just take longer time.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you! Your answer is correct! I missed this error for a whole day and I'm glad to be able to resolve it. Thank you all!